# How to prove error rate of ensemble model by using the Hoeffding's inequality?

Tags: inequality

Under Binary classification situation,
error between function $f$ and basic learner(classifier) $h_i(x)$ is

$$P(h_i(x)≠f(x))=\mathcal{E}$$

It is assumed that T basic classifiers are combined by a voting method, and if more than half of the basic classifiers get the correct answer, it is assumed that the ensemble classifier gives the correct answer.
(Assume T is odd intger for convenience.)

$$H(x) = sign(\sum_{i=1}^T h_i(x))$$

If the error rates of the basic classifier are assumed to be independent of each other, the error rate of the ensemble classifier can be known by the Hoeffding inequality.

$$ P(H(x) ≠ f(x)) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor T/2\rfloor} {}_T \mathrm{ C }_k (1-\mathcal{E})^k \mathcal{E}^{(T-k)} \le exp(-\frac{1}{2}T(1-2\mathcal{E})^2) $$

**I can't understand how the result(exponential part) is derived.**

I think $\lfloor T/2\rfloor = \frac{(T-1)}{2}$ because T is odd integer by the assumption above.

and given basic concept of the Hoeffding inequality of binary classification is
$$P(H(n) \le k) = \sum_{i=0}^{k} {}_n \mathrm{ C }_i \: p^i (1-p)^{(n-i)}
\le exp(-2\mathcal{E}^2n), \; (k=(p- \mathcal{E})n \; and \; \mathcal{E}>0)$$